# How many subnets can we add to aws VPC with different CIDR blocks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, vpc, aws-vpc

I have a VPC with CIDR 26.86.30.192/26.

I created only single subnet with that VPC CIDR (26.86.30.192/26).

Now I'm trying to attach new subnet to exiting VPC and also with new IP block to it with CIDR 46.112.183.128/27 it's not working. Why?

I read this document as well [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Subnets.html#add-cidr-block-restrictions( Adding IPv4 CIDR Blocks to a VPC)]

Answer (score 3):

Your VPC CIDR block is `26.86.30.192/26`. The CIDR block `46.112.183.128/27` that you are trying to allocate to the subnet within the said VPC does not fall within the block `26.86.30.192/26` of that VPC. That's why it is not working.

Also, note that you will not be able to create a second subnet within this VPC as the first subnet has already been assigned the entire CIDR block of the VPC. Reduce the CIDR block size of the first subnet and then try to create a second subnet.
Your VPC size is /26, i.e., it has 64 addresses available.
So, you may create two subnets having 32 addresses each in your VPC with one having the CIDR block as `26.86.30.192/27` and another having the CIDR block as  `26.86.30.224/27`.

Note that the smallest subnet that you can create is a /28 (16 IP addresses). So, in your VPC, you can have a maximum of 4 subnets.
Use this helpful tool at http://cidr.xyz/ to find out the CIDR blocks for these subnets yourself!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a VPC CIDR (26.86.30.192/26) and want to add another subnet to this VPC with CIDR 46.112.183.128/27, its totally on different network which doesn't fall under the VPC CIDR.

If you really want to add 46.112.183.128/27 CIDR subnet, what you are looking for is VPC peering. You can peer 2 different VPC CIDRs and virtually they would be on the same VPC whole together.